# Show customize pop up in recycler view adapter class - Android Java

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-cardview

I have a fragment class that contains edit text,button and the `recycler view`. my recycler view use an xml layout of `card view`. my card view contains text view and a button(?) to show a pop up after being clicked.
[image]

I tried to add the pop up code in my fragment class as I usually do, but it's pointing out that my fragment doesn't have access to recycler's view card view layout. So I tried to add it in my adapter class but I'm getting stuck with `getActivty()` not getting recognize. 
this is what I added in my `view holder` method inside `on click`

````java
                    btnHelp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Popup_FreedomWall popup_freedomWall = new Popup_FreedomWall();
                            Bundle args = new Bundle();
                            System.out.println("=================TVFWID==========================");
                            System.out.println(tvFwId.getText().toString());
                            System.out.println("=====================TVFWID======================");
                            //data to get for report - uid(reported,get reported),freedom wall id
                            args.putString("user", mod_freedomWall.uid_report);
                            args.putString("reportedPost", tvFwId.getText().toString());
                            popup_freedomWall.setArguments(args);

                            popup_freedomWall.show();
                            popup_freedomWall.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "My Fragment");
                        }
                    });
    ```
<br/>
````

`Mod_FreedomWall.java` my Fragment

```java
public class Mod_FreedomWall extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Mod_FreedomWall_UserAdapter myAdapter;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    ArrayList<Mod_FreedomWall_User> user;
  @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mod_freedomwall, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.freedomWallPost);

        return v;

    }

@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.freedomWallPost);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true);
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        btnPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            final Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            final SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy", Locale.getDefault());
            final String formattedDate = df.format(c);
            final Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh.mm aa");
            final String dateString = dateFormat.format(new Date());

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String message = etPost.getText().toString();
                createPost(message, user_name, dateString, formattedDate, level);
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                etPost.setText("");
            }
        });

        user = new ArrayList<Mod_FreedomWall_User>();
        retrievePost();

        myAdapter = new Mod_FreedomWall_UserAdapter(this, user);
        myAdapter.setListener(new Mod_FreedomWall_UserAdapter.MyListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(String uid, String fwid) {
                Popup_FreedomWall popup_freedomWall = new Popup_FreedomWall();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();

  //just to see if I'm getting data              
System.out.println("=================TVFW==========================");
                System.out.println(fwid);
            System.out.println("=====================TVFW======================");

                args.putString("user",uid);
                args.putString("reportedPost", fwid);
                popup_freedomWall.setArguments(args);
                popup_freedomWall.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "pop_upFreedomWall");
            }
        });
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
```

My Adapter

```java
public class Mod_FreedomWall_UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Mod_FreedomWall_UserAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Mod_FreedomWall mod_freedomWall = new Mod_FreedomWall();
    private ArrayList<Mod_FreedomWall_User> user;
    String freeId,reporterId;

    public  Mod_FreedomWall_UserAdapter(Mod_FreedomWall context, ArrayList<Mod_FreedomWall_User> list){
        user = list;
    }
    
public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView ivUserProfile;
        TextView tv_message,tv_username,tv_date,tvTime,tvFwId;
        Button btnHelp;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            btnHelp = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnHelp);
            ivUserProfile = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivUserProfile);
            tv_message = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_message);
            tv_username = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_username);
            tv_date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
            tvTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
            tvFwId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFwId);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnHelp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            System.out.println("=================TVFWID==========================");
                            System.out.println(tvFwId.getText().toString());
                            System.out.println("=====================TVFWID======================");
                            freeId = tvFwId.getText().toString();
                            reporterId = mod_freedomWall.uid_report;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Mod_FreedomWall_UserAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.mod_freedomwall_post,viewGroup,false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Mod_FreedomWall_UserAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        viewHolder.itemView.setTag(user.get(position));

        viewHolder.tvFwId.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        viewHolder.tv_message.setText(user.get(position).getMessage());
        viewHolder.tv_username.setText(user.get(position).getUsername());
        viewHolder.tv_date.setText(user.get(position).getDate());
        viewHolder.tvTime.setText(user.get(position).getTime());
        viewHolder.tvFwId.setText(user.get(position).getFreedomWallId());
        viewHolder.ivUserProfile.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_username_white);

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return user.size();
    }
    public interface MyListener {
        void onItemClicked(String uid,String fwid); 
    }

    MyListener mListener;


    public void setListener(MyListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you have two possible approaches to this problem.

1. Send a Context with in your Adapter's constructor and replace the part where you need the "getActivity()" with that context you passed through (obv via a variable in your Adapter).
2. Use an Interface approach.
   I never like the Context style, so I'll give you an example for an Interface approach.

In your Adapter:

```
public abstract class YourAdapter extends ...<> {

    public interface MyListener {
        void onItemClicked(String someData); //can change this variable to whatever is needed, if any.
    }

    MyListener mListener;
    ...
```

Then let the onClickListener of the button call the Interface function you just created instead of trying to make a popup directly:

```
    btnHelp.setOnClickListener(v -> onItemClicked("this is my data i pass through");
```

Then add a function to your Adapter to set the listener (or add it as argument in the constructor, whatever you want):

```
public void setListener(MyListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }
```

And implement the listener in your Fragment:

```
adapter.setListener(new YourAdapter.MyListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(String myData) {
            //create your popup and simply call getActivity() since this is inside the Fragment
        }
    });
```

--- Your Fragment ---

```
public class Mod_FreedomWall extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter myAdapter; //<-- 1 *remove*
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager; // obsolete, can be deleted. You make a local variable later on.
    Mod_FreedomWall_UserAdapter adapter; // <-- 2 *rename to myAdapter*
  @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mod_freedomwall, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.freedomWallPost);

        return v;

    }

@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.freedomWallPost);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true);
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

// You call a function of `adapter` here, but adapter hasn't been 
// properly initialised yet, it's null so far, so that won't go well. 
// *rename adapter to myAdapter and move this part down*
adapter.setListener(new Mod_FreedomWall_UserAdapter.MyListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(String uid, String fwid) {
                Popup_FreedomWall popup_freedomWall = new Popup_FreedomWall();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                //data to get for report - uid(reported,get reported),freedom wall id
                args.putString("user",uid);
                args.putString("reportedPost", fwid);
                popup_freedomWall.setArguments(args);
                popup_freedomWall.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "My Fragment");
            }
        });

        btnPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            final Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            final SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy", Locale.getDefault());
            final String formattedDate = df.format(c);
            final Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh.mm aa");
            final String dateString = dateFormat.format(new Date());

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String message = etPost.getText().toString();
                createPost(message, user_name, dateString, formattedDate, level);
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                etPost.setText("");
            }
        });

        user = new ArrayList<Mod_FreedomWall_User>();
        retrievePost();

        //Here you initialise your adapter
        myAdapter = new Mod_FreedomWall_UserAdapter(this, user);
        //you can move your `myAdapter.setListener` to this spot.
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
```

Well, you declared two adapters but only really used one. Seems a bit mixed up.

To-do;
Scrap one of the adapters (number 1). Then the simplest way is to rename `adapter` at number 2 to `myAdapter` and also change the `adapter` at `adapter.setListener` to `myAdapter.setListener(...`.

Then move that `myAdapater.setListener(...` to a place below `myAdapter = new Mod_FreedomWall_UserAdapter(this, user);` since that is where you actually initialise your adapter. Before that point you can't safely call the your adapter's functions.

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer. I tried to implement it in my code as per your instructions, but I got lost on the last part which is to implement the listener in my fragment. What is adapter there? and where am I suppose to put the code? in `onViewCreated`? sorry I'm new in android.

Comment: "adapter" is the adapter-variable which you initialised in your Fragment to attach to the RecyclerView. Somewhere you probably have a line like "recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)", the part between the brackets is the one I aim for, you may have called it something else - replace the `adapter` in my example with the name you have used. And yes, you can place it in the `onViewCreated` as long as your `adapter` has been initialised before that point. If you still have a problem, then you may want to add your Fragment code to your post so we can take a better look :)

Comment: I'm still having problem on the last part. here's what I did, I used `myAdapter.setListener(new adapter.MyListener()` and it's giving me an error in that whole line so I tried `adapter.setListener(new Mod_FreedomWall_UserAdapter.MyListener()` and it's not showing me an error in the compiler but when I run the  app, it's saying that MyListerner is null.
ps. I added my fragment code above :)

Comment: I edited my post with comments in your code and some indicators where to make changes. Hope that helps a little

Comment: I found my mistakes now, your instructions was great and it was just me who didn't get it. My first mistake was on how I wasn't passing anything in the `MyListener { void onItemClicked(String uid,String fwid);  }` on clicking the button `btnHelp` you can see my  mistake above as I posted `My Adapter class` too. then my second mistake was in the fragment. Thank you it helps a lot!